# Unexpected result from predictor matrix, quickpred function and md.pattern function

Tags: multiple-imputation, mice

I try to impute value into the Titanic data set from Kaggle. However, when I inspect some of the variables before imputing. I think I got some unexpected result.
[image]

1- In predictor matrix, there are three columns that have missing values, Age, Cabin and Embarked but in the matrix, only Age is getting imputing.
2- When I try to check on quickpred function, it instead suggest me to impute Ticket which has no missing value at all.
3- In md.pattern function, I got a really wired result. According to my understanding of the matrix, it says that I got missing value in Ticket, Name and Sex as well. However, as I check on the data, there is no missing value on those columns at all.
I can just change the predictor matrix manually but I want to know why mice decide to put the pattern and predictor matrix that way?